# stripe connect bank account verification on selection of country

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

hello i am working with stripe connect and i want create interface where user select its country and according to his country system should ask the account verification information below is the code of my country select box

```
 <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                                                    <label for="country" class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-form-label">
                                                        Country <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
                                                        <select name="account-country"
                                                                class="form-control account input-lg"
                                                                id="account-country" data-stripe="country">
                                                            <option value="US">United States</option>
                                                            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                                                            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                                                            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                                                            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                                                            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
                                                            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                                                            <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                                                            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                                                            <option value="FR">France</option>
                                                            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                                                            <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
                                                            <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
                                                            <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                                                            <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                                                            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                                                            <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
                                                            <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                                                            <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
                                                            <option value="NO">Norway</option>
                                                            <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                                                            <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
                                                            <option value="ES">Spain</option>
                                                            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
                                                            <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

can i have any jquery plugin or stripe.js for this or i need to make it custom 
please help me about this

Comment: Stripe has [an API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/country_specs/object?lang=php) that you can use to determine which verification fields you need to collect for a particular country which is likely what you need in order to implement this, but I don't have a pre-built example of using it.

Comment: i want js for front end which is running like when i change country it change the field required like for us only routing number needed and for us bank name , branch name , bank code ,branch code, account owner name need so when us only routing number will be required and for japan all the above defined information will be required and like this for all countries